# Induction Proof: Prove that if $|N(w)| = 3^k$ for $k\geq 0$, then $N(w) = (-3)^k$.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I posted this yesterday asking for help and was told it was unclear what I was asking. I continued to work on it and think I have completed the proof, so now I just am hoping I can get verification that the proof holds.

Proof:
Prove by induction that if $w$ is an extended integer, that is $w = a+\sqrt{3}b$, and that $|N(w)| = w\cdot \bar{w} = a^2-3b^2 = 3^k$ for $k\geq 0$, then $N(w) = (-3)^k$.

We proceed with induction. We begin with the base case, $k=0$.
We have $|N(w)| = 3^0 = 1$, which implies that $N(w) = \pm1$. We see that $N(w) = 1 = (-3)^0$ and we know, from past exercises, that there are no extended integers such that $N(w) = -1$ so the base case holds true for $k=0$.

Next, we assume the case for $n$ where $1\leq n \leq k$ to be true, that is, if $|N(w)| = 3^n$, then $N(w) = (-3)^n$ is true. Now we must prove that if $|N(w)| = 3^{n+1}$, then $N(w) = (-3)^{n+1}$ for $1\leq n+1 \leq k$. We have $N(w) = (-3)^{n+1} = a^2-3b^2$. Rearranging this equation, we are left with $a^2 = (-3)^{n+1}+3b^2 = 3((-3)^{n}-b^2)$. This implies, from previous exercises, that since $a^2$ is divisible by $3$, then $a$ is also divisible by $3$. We say that $a = 3t$, for some integer $t$, substituting $a$ into the $N(w)$ equation we are left with $N(w) = (3t)^2-3b^2 = 9t^2-3b^2 = -3(b^2-3t^2) = (-3)^{n+1}$.
Factoring out a $-3$ from the right end of the above equation, we are left with
$-3(b^2 - 3t^2) = -3(-3)^n$ and so, $b^2-3t^2 = (-3)^n$ which we already have assumed to be true, hence the statement is proven.

Comment: Looks like you're using what you want to prove.  "We have $N(w) = (-3)^{n+1} = a^2 - 3b^2$.  Rearranging this equation..."  It actually looks like you're starting with $N(w) = (-3)^{n+1}$ and using it to show $N(w) = (-3)^n$, which is incorrect and doesn't make sense.  $N(w)$ can't be equal to both of those things at the same time.

Comment: @tilper so you're saying I need to set $(-3)^{n+1}$ equal to different integers, say $c^2-3d^2$? I thought with induction that we try to prove the same thing for subsequent values $n,n+1,n+2$, etc.?

Comment: For the inductive step you need to start with your inductive hypothesis and conclude with the result you want.  You can't start with the result you want and conclude with the hypothesis.  That doesn't prove the desired result is true.  For example, $-1 = 1$, square both sides and get $1=1$.  It's true  that $1=1$ but the starting point, $-1 = 1$, is false.  In your case you just don't want to start by saying $N(w) = (-3)^{n+1}$ because that's exactly what you want to prove.

Comment: OH! lol you definitely just gave me a "eureka" moment, thank you so much!